# How customize spring validator?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-validator

I want to write custom validator with complex logic that depends on some properties that must be set in starup. It is possible to write component-scan tag in spring configuration file, but how to set other properties in class or spring validater are used as stateless classess?

```
public class CustomValidator implements Validator{
    private Map<String,Integer> parameters;

     public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return ObjectToValidate.class.equals(clazz);    
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        ObjectToValidate  object = (ObjectToValidate) obj;

        switch (parameters.get(object.getIntegerProperty())) {
            case 1:
                //validation algorithm 1;
                break;

            case 2:
                //validation algorithm 2;
                break;

            //etc.
        }
    }

    public void setParameters(Map<String,Integer> parameters){
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set up in your app context a `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean`.

It will inject your validators with every `@Autowired` property they need. If you don't want to use autowiring, you should add them to your app context as beans.

Give a look here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html

Everything is explained.

Stefano